# Load Japanese Text into UIWebView

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, epub

I'm making an app for read epub book with Japanese language. In general, web view will load text from html and display in web view from left to right and from top to bottom, but my app requires display text in web view follow text from top to bottom and then from left to right, so is there any solution for displaying text in UIWebView follow above format, thanks for your helps...

Comment: Interesting. Does EPUB itself support this page flow?

Comment: i dont know, but i have downloaded many japanese ebook with epub format from this site [link](http://aozora.wook.jp/), and those books is typical read from left to right

Comment: ePub 3 does support this, as does iBooks 3.0 and Kobo reader.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the CSS property `writing-mode: vertical-rl`.

However, this is a broad topic. You'll probably need to tweak other properties such as `text-orientation` (to position non-CJK glyphs upright when necessary), `text-combine` (to group two numbers horizontally in a single character "cell", and so on.

In any case, beware, you are now in an alternate universe with basic concepts like "left" now changing their meaning on you.